# jQuery unassign itself after loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, cs-cart

We have a CS-Cart store that we recently moved the directories on. After the move, we have found that the Javascript on the home page is not working correctly. A number of `$(document).ready()` events aren't working correctly and are throwing a `TypeError: $ is not a function` error.

After stepping through the concatenated file, we have narrowed the problem down. The file is processed correctly but after the first `$(document).ready()` event is called, jQuery seems to unassign itself. IE both the `jQuery` and `$` variables are unset.

We have access to a wayback machine copy of the site and that seems to work properly. If we copy the old javascript file across though, we get the same error. This fact seems to suggest that it is some other mechanism that is causing the problem.

Is there a known mechanism that CS-Cart or jQuery will unassign the jQuery variables?

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that the MailChimp embed code was  old and the jQuery noConflict method was causing the issues. Once we turned the embed code off, everything worked as expected.